# Trouble clicking submit button in selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

I am trying to click the submit button in the login page for my router, but am having trouble doing so.

Here is a screenshot of the login page: 
[image: screenshot]

I know I need to do some sort of `driver.find_element_by_something()`, but cannot figure out what to call it on.

here is what I use to fill in the forms

```
driver.get("http://172.18.40.177:8080/index.html")
username = driver.find_element_by_name("userid2")
username.send_keys("admin")

password = driver.find_element_by_name("passwd2")
password.send_keys("cyber")
```

[html webpage](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/18b2528eab3ca59e66fdfe62bec77318)

Comment: please paste the code to codepen or something similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without your code and seeing the rest of the html it's hard to say. something like the below will probably work

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("descendant::tr/td/img").Click();
```

the thing is if there's other img tags within a td it may find those first. In that case you'll have to do some analysis on the html to figure out a way to select the button but xpath is likely your best bet.